# Html data gathering

Tags: html, html-table

I tried gathering table data but I didn't quite get it. Does anyone know how to gather data with any method?

```html
<table name="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>Your age:</td>
    <td><input type="number" name="age" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this

```
<tr>                  
<td>Your age:</td>
<td><input type="number" name="age" id="age_value" /></td>
</tr>
```

Get the input value using this query

```
document.getElementById("age_value").value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a backend to collect the data

For example, you can use PHP or Python to build a backend run in your server

And in the frontend, the part of html, you can use `form` element to post the data to the backend or you can use js to write a POST request to send the data to the backend

Then, you can write some operation to hold the data in your server, like use the SQL

Like the code in https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp